# What does this code do?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-6

```
if (in_array($form['#submit'], 'search_box_form_submit')) {
    $key = array_search('search_box_form_submit', $form['#submit']);
    unset($form['#submit'][$key]);
}

array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_search_box_submit');
```

What does the code do? I don't follow it well; I expect someone can explain it to me, line by line.

Comment: unlikely this is the "right" approach, but without context that's just a educated guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (in_array($form['#submit'], 'search_box_form_submit')) {`

If the value `'search_box_form_submit'` is present in the array `$form['#submit']`

`$key = array_search('search_box_form_submit', $form['#submit']);`

Then set the variable `$key` to the array key for the value `'search_box_form_submit'` in the array `$form['#submit']`

`unset($form['#submit'][$key]);`

Then unset (delete) that array element

`array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_search_box_submit');`

Put a new element at the beginning of the array `$form['#submit']` with the value `'mymodule_search_box_submit'`

Answer (score 2):

If the submitted form contains a variable named "search_box_form_submit", delete it, and then add a new variable called "mymodule_search_box_submit".

Perhaps somebody wanted to override the drupal search function and didn't want the default processor to fire at all. Thanks kiamlaluno in the comments.

Comment: this definitely smells bad... no doubt there was a better way to achieve what this code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: It would not smell bad, if somebody is altering the Drupal search box, and he wants to avoid the original form submission handler is executed.

Answer (score 1):

is the text "search_box_form_submit" in the array $form['#submit']
if so find the key for search_box_form_submit
then remove from array

put the value mymodule_search_box_submit in the front of the array $form['#submit']

i recommend reading the manual page for the functions used.